# How to check image extension on Android?

Tags: android, imagedownload

I'm retrieving posts from Facebook, I want to save data in database, but for images and photos I need to download them but I need to determine the extension of the image but using splitting is not useful all times since the link differs. Is there a way to determine the extension?

My code:

```
  public static String DownLoadFile(String netUrl, String savePath, String name, String ext) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(netUrl);
            File file = new File(savePath, name + "." + ext);

   /* Open a connection to that URL. */
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d("DownloadManager", "download begining");
        Log.d("DownloadManager", "downloaded file name:" + name);


        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }


           /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        Log.d("DownloadManager", "download ready in" + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");

        return file.getAbsolutePath();


    } catch (Exception exx) {
        if (exx.getMessage() != null) {

            Log.w(Error_Tag, "Err3 = " + exx.getMessage());
        } else {
            Log.w(Error_Tag, "Err3 = " + exx.getMessage());

        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I see the problem concerning split, but couldnt you just extract like the last 5-10 characters of your link and split them?

Answer (score 1):

[`MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html#getFileExtensionFromUrl%28java.lang.String%29) is what you are looking for.

Comment: thnx.But if i want to save the image by its id how can i get it from the url.

Comment: One way is to use the ([getPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#getPath())) method from which you can get the file name.

Comment: but when i run the code it gives this error: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory).i added write permission on external storage